# The monomial representation of $S_n$ is irreducible.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, invariant-theory

I am going through "Linear group representations" by Ernest Vinberg
The example is given below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**But I have difficulties in understanding the following:**

1- why $V_{0}$ is called $(n-1)-$dimensional subspace, I want a concrete example please?

2- Why if the characteristic of the field $K$ is equal to zero, then $V_{1}$ is not subset of $V_{0}$?

3- I do not understand how he calculated $M((12))x - x$, could anyone clarify this for me?

4- Now I am stuck on this question (the above example is example 5):

[image]

Comment: Dear hopefully, I like the 4th part of the question concerning restriction to $A_n$. Could you arrange it as a separate question?

Comment: It is better to address particular terminology in question headings, and type your questions instead of adding pictures where possible. The heading "Task n from book m" makes your question unsearchable. You can remove "Difficulty understanding ..." from the heading with no harm as well.

Comment: This article explains why I bother about it: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer to the first three questions:

- $V_0$ is defined by a single linear equation. The general result is this: if a subspace is defined by a system of linear equations of rank $r$  (i.e. the matrix with rows the coefficients of the defining linear equations has rank $r$), this subspace has *codimension* $r$, which means that in a space of dimension $n$, it has dimension $n-r$. This is because you can determine $r$ coordinates in function of the $n-r$ others (cf. the way to solve linear systems of equations).
- $V_0$ is defined by the equation $x_1+x_2+ +\dots +x_n=0$, whereas all vectors in $V_1$ satisfy $x_i=x_j \:\forall i,j$, so that for such a vector, $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=nx_1$, which is $\ne 0$, except for the null vector, or if the characteristic of $K$ is a prime factor of $n$.
- If $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+\sum_{i=3}^n x_ie_i$, we have, by linearity,
  $$M((1\,2))x=x_1e_2+x_2e_1+\sum_{i=3}^n x_ie_i,$$
  so that
  \begin{align}
  M((1\,2))x-x&=x_1e_2+x_2e_1+\sum_{i=3}^n x_ie_i-\Bigl(x_1e_1+x_2e_2+\sum_{i=3}^n x_ie_i\Bigr),\\
  &=x_1e_2+x_2e_1-(x_1e_1+x_2e_2)=x_2e_1-x_1e_1+x_1e_2-x_2e_2\\
  &=\dotsm
  \end{align}

Comment: what does it mean $\sum x_{i}$ = 0 , why we lose one dimension by this assumption could you give a concrete example please?

Comment: Can you give me a numeric example for $V_{0}$ please?

Comment: Yes: e.g. in $V=\mathbf R^3$, $V_0$ is the plane defined by the equation $x+y+z=0$. It also can be defined by $3$ non- collinear points (as any plane). We may take for these $(0,1,-1),\:$ $(-1,0,1)\:$ and $(1,-1,0)$. As to your other question, we lose one dimension because, once we know any $n-1$ coordinates of a point in $V_0$, the $n$-th coordinate can be deduced from this relation. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is $(n-1)$-dimensional because it has a basis with $n-1$ elements:$$\{e_1-e_2,e_2-e_3,\ldots,e_{n-1}-e_n\}.$$
2. The set $V_1$ is not a subset of $V_0$ because $e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_n\in V_1\setminus V_0$, since $\overbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}^{n\text{ terms}}\neq0$ (because $K$ has characteristic $0$).
3. Did you read the definition if $M(\sigma)$? By this definition, $M\bigl((1\ \ 2)\bigr)(e_1)=e_2$, $M\bigl((1\ \ 2)\bigr)(e_2)=e_1$, and $M\bigl((1\ \ 2)\bigr)(e_k)=e_k$ if $k>2$. Therefore, if $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+\cdots+x_ne_n$, then$$M\bigl((1\ \ 2)\bigr)(x_1e_1+x_2e_2+\cdots+x_ne_n)=x_2e_1+x_1e_2+x_3e_3+\cdots+x_ne_n.$$
4. I suspect that Vinberg stated some result (about group characters, perhaps) to prove this, but I don't have his book at hand right now.

Comment: and why it has a basis with n-1 elements?

Comment: Because that set that I mentioned spans $V_0$, it is linearly independent and it has $n-1$ elements.

Comment: Why the set you mentioned spans $V_{0}$ .... why it takes specially this form $e_{i} - e_{i +1}$ ...... why it is not expressed in terms of $e_{i}$'s only?

Comment: It spans $V_0$ because if $v\in V_0$, then $v=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+\cdots+x_nv_n$, with $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=0$, and therefore$$v=x_1(x_1-e_2)+(x_1+x_2)(e_2-e_3)+(x_1+x_2+x_3)(e_3-e_4)+\cdots+(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n-1})(e_{n-1}-e_n).$$

Comment: I think in your last inequality in the first term it should be $(e_{1} - e_{2})$ instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right.